# How to delete values from an unsigned integer array in rust

Tags: arrays, rust

I am trying to write a function that removes all occurrences of 1,2 and 3 from an array of unsigned integers. I have used the retain method but the error I am getting is:

```
rustc -o main main.rs
error[E0599]: no method named `retain` found for array `[u32; 7]` in the current scope
 --> main.rs:3:5
  |
3 | arr.retain(|&x| x != 1 || x != 2 || x != 3);
  |     ^^^^^^ method not found in `[u32; 7]`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
compiler exit status 1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
fn remover(arr:[u32;7]){

arr.retain(|&x| x != 1 || x != 2 || x != 3);
println!("{:?}",arr);

}

fn main() {
    let v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    remover(v);
    
}
```

Why can I not use the retain method? Is there something else I can use?

Answer (score 3):

An array has a fixed size (`[u32; 7]` will always have 7 elements), therefore it doesn't make sense to remove elements from it.

If you want a dynamically sized sequence, you should use `Vec`, which does have a [`retain` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain).

Or you could keep an array and use [`Iterator::filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter), if you don't actually need to update the source.

Comment: Can I make a new array instead by adding all the values I don't want to delete in it?

Comment: You can use [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) on your iterator to collect into a `Vec<T>`. Collecting into an array is not supported yet, due to the compile-time size of arrays.

Comment: Though you could initialise a zeroed array and fill it in by hand. Adding dependency, there's the option of [ArrayVec](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are statically sized in Rust, its size is part of the type. `[u32; 7]` defines the array to hold exactly 7 `u32` values.

If you want to have a dynamic number of values, you will need to use `Vec<u32>` instead, i.e. declare `v` as `vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and make your `remover()` take `Vec<u32>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, you can proceed to filter to a **slice** of your array. By doing you do not duplicate data, avoiding creating a new vector.

```
fn main()
{
    let v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    let v_filtered = &v
        .iter()
        .filter(|&&x| x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3)
        .inspect(|&&x| println!("retained {}", x))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    dbg!(v);
    dbg!(v_filtered);
}
```

Pay attention, I changed the predicate of my filter.
Here is my [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a5cda37cb84cd2879c3ad81060b91be)

You can remove debugging info and iteration inspection value for the release version.